How to set allowed cipher suite to management console port on JBoss EAP 7?
I know that there are examples about how to set enabled-cipher-suites to https-listener, but it doesn't seem like there is a example about how to set allowed cipher suites to management-https? which I need that to pass the port scanner that indicated that this management console port is vulnerable because it uses weak ciphers.
Does anyone know how to set that?
